# Android - strange layout display in custom DialogPreference

Tags: java, android, layout, preference

I have a custom DialogPreference with my own layout defined. The layout file is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter_password_label"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/confirm_password_label"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword" 
    />
```

On the displayed dialog both TextViews are missing:

[image]

What is the reason of TextViews not being displayed?

Comment: Have you tried to change the color of Text

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for this behavior is due to manufacturer's customization of themes. Other reasons could be that the selected text appearance has same color as of background. To avoid this, you may simply set a *color* to your TextView, for e.g.:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter_password_label"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

**Also make sure `android:text` does have a text to show on screen*